# Configuring flash block table in vector GENy

Tags: memory, bootloader, memory-mapping

I am trying to configure the flash block table in Vector GENy. I have
the following questions:

1. How to decide the starting address of first flash block table?
2. How to decide on sector size length in flash block table?
3. If the sector size length in logical memory is same as sector size in physical memory?
4. Is the total length of the logical memory equal to physical memory: My understanding is that there is some mapping in the form of translation/ look up table that maps the physical address to logical address.

Answer (score 0):

The information for your flash block table usually comes from the user/ reference manual of your MCU or some attachment.

As you are talking about GENy, I suspect that you got a demonstration project with it.
In this case, you can take this as an example, which probably already fits your MCU.

The logical block table is there to have an entry for every logical software block you want to have reflashable (or not) in your FBL.

The flash blocks can then be mapped to your logical blocks.
BTW, there are variants in which this mapping is itself a logical block, which can be reflashed.

I guess that most people order a startup support package with their flash boot loader.
If you have that, they will help you with the initial setup.